# how to iterate through all nested dict element in python

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I have dict with below data.

```
{'Night': {'time': '22:00:00', 'setPoint': 140}, 'Day': {'time': '08:00:00', 'setPoint': 139}, 'Morning': {'time': '06:00:00', 'setPoint': 110}, 'Evening': {'time': '18:00:00', 'setPoint': 130}}
```

I want a list which contains only time
Sample output:

```
['22:00:00','08:00:00','06:00:00','18:00:00']
```

Comment: Can you highlight what the link with Test automation framework:  Robot Framework is?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
result = [subdict['time'] for _, subdict in dic.items()]

print(result)
```

Produces the following output:

```
['22:00:00', '08:00:00', '06:00:00', '18:00:00']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.values()` method of a dictionary:

```
>>> d={'Night': {'time': '22:00:00', 'setPoint': 140}, 'Day': {'time': '08:00:00', 'setPoint': 139}, 'Morning': {'time': '06:00:00', 'setPoint': 110}, 'Evening': {'time': '18:00:00', 'setPoint': 130}}
>>> [v['time'] for v in d.values()]
['22:00:00', '08:00:00', '06:00:00', '18:00:00']
```